# Extract words from url

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have this url and I want to extract some words from it:

```
import re

url  = 'https://sub-domain.s3.amazonaws.com/applications/12345678987654/dates/2020-08-13/filename.csv.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=fakeaccesskey&Expires=1597403610&Signature=fakeSignature)'
pattern = re.compile(
    r'[https://sub-domain.s3.amazonaws.com/applications/12345678987654/dates/2020-08\-13/](?P<filename>)[.csv.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=](?P<keyId>)[&Expires=](?P<expire>)[&Signature=](?P<signature>)')
m = pattern.search(url)
filename = m.group('filename')
keyId = m.group('keyId')
expire = m.group('expire')
signature = m.group('signature')

print(filename)
print(keyId)
print(expire)
print(signature)
```

When executed my code, I got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`.
I did the job using `urlparse` but I want to use the regex lib.

Comment: why is your url containing groups? read about escaping - your pattern contains special chars that need that.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know anything about `Regex` sorry. But this can be accomplished with string slicing. Assuming the Url above is correct, the following code will grab the required parts.

```
url  = 'https://sub-domain.s3.amazonaws.com/applications/12345678987654/dates/2020-08-13/(?P<filename>.csv.gz?AWSAccessKeyId=fakeaccesskey&Expires=1597403610&Signature=fakeSignature)'

filename = url.split("/")[-1].split("?A")[0]
keyId = url.split("AWSAccessKeyId=")[1].split("&")[0]
expire = url.split("Expires=")[1].split("&")[0]
signature = url.split("Signature=")[1]
```